# Can I free storage space by creating a mock file and forcing iCloud to upload content to the cloud?

Tags: icloud, storage

I have a MacBook Pro and I wanted to make room on its hard drive. My current 256G HD has 110 GB occupied by iCloud, despite using the iCloud optimization feature. The consequence is that I have only 20G of free space, which I would like to increase to 30G. As folks know, the amount of free space is automatically set by Apple's algorithms. So, here is my question: if I create a mock file with random content (say, a 20G file), will this somehow "force" the algorithm to upload some of the non-used files to the cloud, thus allowing me to delete the mock file and free the space (at least for a small amount of time)?

Comment: Why don‘t you just try? :-)

Answer (score 1):

That is a legitimate strategy, one I’ve used before!

However, there’s a better way that was added in macOS Catalina: right-click a file or folder in iCloud downloaded locally and choose Remove Download. This will offload the content locally and free space.

Comment: Awesome. I will try it out. One of the reasons why I want to do this is to create HD space to upgrade to Catalina. :-)